# I can't figure out how to reset labels after it's been displayed in tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a Calculator and the whole thing is almost done, but after the answer has been displayed I want it to reset so a new answer can be displayed. Otherwise it will just be a mess of random number. So I was basically wondering if anyone knew a some sort of reset command that'll work here. More intel is in the code itself(AKA what label). Here's the code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

#This is where "Svar" or in English "answer" is being defined.
def Kalk(event):
    if operator.get() == "+":
        global Svar
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) + int(Nummer_2.get())
        Answer(event)
    elif operator.get() == "-":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) - int(Nummer_2.get())
        Answer(event)
    elif operator.get() == "*":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) * int(Nummer_2.get())
        Answer(event)
    elif operator.get() == "/":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) / int(Nummer_2.get())
        Answer(event)
    else:
        Svar = ("Vennligst velg et av alternativene overfor")
        Answer(event)

#This is where it displays "Svar" which is "answer".
def Answer(event):
#I want this label("Label_4") to be reset so when I run this def again the numbers won't stack
    label_4 = Label(topFrame, text=Svar)
    label_4.grid(row=6)
    print(Svar)


kalkis = Tk()
kalkis.geometry("300x250")
kalkis.title("Kalkulator")
topFrame = Frame(kalkis)
topFrame.grid(row=0)
label = Label(topFrame, text="Du kan velge mellom '+', '-', '*'. '/' ")
label.grid(row=0)
operator = Entry(topFrame)
operator.grid(row=1)
label_2 = Label(topFrame, text="Skriv inn hvilket tall du vil bruke ")
label_2.grid(row=2)
Nummer_1 = Entry(topFrame)
#Nummer_1 = int(answer.get())
Nummer_1.grid(row=3)
Label_3 = Label(topFrame, text="Skriv inn ditt andre tall ")
Label_3.grid(row=4)
Nummer_2 = Entry(topFrame)
#Nummer_2 = int(answer.get())
Nummer_2.grid(row=5)
#Nummer_2.bind("<Return>", Kalk())


Refresh = Button(topFrame, text="Enter", command=kalkis)
Refresh.bind("<Enter>", Kalk)
Refresh.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

#Refresh.bind("<Return>", Kalk())


kalkis.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to change a `Label()` is to associate it to a textvariable of type `StringVar()`. Any updates to the textvariable will propagate to the label. Eg.

```
display_text = StringVar()
label_4 = Label(topFrame, textvariable=display_text)
```

The function `Answer()` creates a new label each time it is called. Instead just create the label one time and then update the textvariable for each calculation.

```
import time
from tkinter import *

#This is where "Svar" or in English "answer" is being defined.
def Kalk(event):
    if operator.get() == "+":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) + int(Nummer_2.get())
        display_text.set(str(Svar))     # Update textvariable
    elif operator.get() == "-":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) - int(Nummer_2.get())
        display_text.set(str(Svar))     # Update textvariable
    elif operator.get() == "*":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) * int(Nummer_2.get())
        display_text.set(str(Svar))     # Update textvariable
    elif operator.get() == "/":
        Svar = int(Nummer_1.get()) / int(Nummer_2.get())
        display_text.set(str(Svar))     # Update textvariable
    else:
        Svar = ("Vennligst velg et av alternativene overfor")
        display_text.set(Svar)          # Update textvariable

kalkis = Tk()
kalkis.geometry("300x250")
kalkis.title("Kalkulator")
topFrame = Frame(kalkis)
topFrame.grid(row=0)
label = Label(topFrame, text="Du kan velge mellom '+', '-', '*'. '/' ")
label.grid(row=0)
operator = Entry(topFrame)
operator.grid(row=1)
label_2 = Label(topFrame, text="Skriv inn hvilket tall du vil bruke ")
label_2.grid(row=2)
Nummer_1 = Entry(topFrame)
Nummer_1.grid(row=3)
Label_3 = Label(topFrame, text="Skriv inn ditt andre tall ")
Label_3.grid(row=4)
Nummer_2 = Entry(topFrame)
Nummer_2.grid(row=5)

# This is where it displays "Svar" which is "answer".
display_text = StringVar()  # Create a StringVar() to hold the result
label_4 = Label(topFrame, textvariable=display_text) # Associate to label
label_4.grid(row=6)

Refresh = Button(topFrame, text="Enter", command=kalkis)
Refresh.bind("<Enter>", Kalk)
Refresh.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

kalkis.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You're an everyday hero xD

Comment: Got a new weird problem, the calc won't update now..? Do you know what could cause this?This is the error: display_text.set(str(Svar))
NameError: name 'display_text' is not defined

Comment: Hmmm..., I don't get that error running my example. But from the error message there is somewhere that `display_text` is not defined. The most usual scenarios are: you have misspelled the variable name or you have defined tha variable name in a local scope and can't accsess it from global namespace. If it's not any of those errors then please start a new question with the code which generates this error.

Comment: I made it work! I just didnt move the label def further down like you did so it didnt know.